# Resize PopUp window on Form submit

Tags: javascript, html

I want to resize `PopUp window` when `HTML Form` is submitted. I mean i want to open the `Form response` in same `popup` window but resized to different `height and width`.

How can i do that. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do that by using `window.resizeTo(width, height);` in the response page.